# Is it possible to If statement "article already appears on page"?

Tags: conditional-tags

Best is an example:

Front page. I want to have a featured section at top. If A Science post is in my Featured, I don't want it to also show in my Science section of the same page.

Can I If-Statement this somehow? Like: "If the_post already appeared, do not list"?

I'd like to add this to the other category's displaying as sections on that page as well, so a post categorized Science and Health just displays on one.

Thanks for any tips or if you got this one.

J

Comment: You can use post categorization to do this or create custom taxonomy for that particular post type. In that case you can use taxonomy queries.

Comment: I assume Science is a category here, If a post is a featured post from this category either you are making this post a sticky or setting some meta key like as featured_post, so when you show all the post from this category to the science section page exclude sticky post or featured_post meta value in the query.

Comment: Sort of. So I display posts at the top of the front with a tag (eg "front") These posts are also checked for their categories (eg a post may be tagged "front" and categorized "Science," "Health," "Cancer" (child-category to "Health"). I want the front to just show the post once though (wherever it appears first -- in this case, its tag. If it wasn't tagged, it would show with the Science (second highest category on the page).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply build an array of ID's of posts from the loops and then just exclude those posts from the following set of queries

I don't know your exact structure, but here is a very basic idea (*Requires PHP5.4+ due to short array syntax (`[]`), for older versions, change back to old array syntax (`array()`)*)

```
// Define the variable to hold posts 
$remove_duplicates = [];

// define and run our first query
$args1 = [
    // All your arguments for this query
];
$loop1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );
if ( $loop1->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop1->have_posts() ) {
    $loop1->the_post();

        // Build our array of ID's to exclude from other query
        $remove_duplicates[] = get_the_ID();

        // Rest of your loop

    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // VERY VERY IMPORTANT
}

// Define our second query and exclude posts from the first
$args2 = [
    'post__not_in' => $remove_duplicates, // Remove posts from from $loop1
    // All your arguments for this query
];
$loop2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
if ( $loop2->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop2->have_posts() ) {
    $loop2->the_post();

        // Rest of your loop

    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // VERY VERY IMPORTANT
}
```

Comment: Please do not keep your questions open. If my answer solved the issue, accept it please, otherwise if you used your own solution, post it as an answer and accept your own answer.This way you help us keeping the site "clean" ;-)